# Django filtering by a value which might be in a many-to-many field

Tags: django, django-models

Lets say we have a Driver model, and a Driver might own many cars. I want to be able to filter a `QuerySet` so that I can see all the drivers who drive a specific car. I.e:

```
class Driver(models.Model):
    primary_car = models.ForeignKey(Car, related_name='primary')
    cars = models.ManyToMany(Car, related_name = 'all')

    def save(self, force_insert=False, force_update=False, using=None, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.primary_car not in self.cars.all():
            self.cars.add(self.primary_car)
        super(Car, self).save(force_insert=False, force_update=False, using=None, *args, **kwargs)

class Car(models.Models):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

So let's say I have 50 drivers, and I know that 7 have Yugos and that 2 have Yugos as their primary car. How do I search for these drivers? I thought it would take less than 2 minutes of googling to find this answer, so I'm probably missing something basic.

UPDATE: I fixed the mangled `save()` method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from django.db.models import Q

# drivers who have either have a "Yugo" as their primary car,
# or have a relation to one
yugo_drivers = Driver.objects.filter(Q(primary_car__name__iexact="Yugo") | 
                                     Q(cars__name__iexact="Yugo"))
```

Two things that will help you out are:

- [Lookups that span relationships](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships)
- [Q objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I barely knew about the `Q-thingie` <- `a technical term`. So your answer is particularly helpful to me.

Comment: No problem. Q objects give you a means to do "OR" lookups among other things.

Answer (score 0):

```
qs = Driver.objects.filter(Car_name=your_car.name)
```